# Xcode 4.2 codesense - how do you narrow down the suggested completion list?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2

Is there any way in Xcode to narrow down the completion list displayed by CodeSense as you type when you have several methods that all start with same prefix?

For example: 
Lets assume you have subclassed UITableViewController and wish to implement the method

```
-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

So, you start to type:

```
-tableView
```

and you get the following CodeSense completion list

[image: Screenshot of CodeSense completion popup for -tableView]

That's great, but there are *loads* of available suggestions and scrolling through this list seems to defeat the point of CodeSense.

How do you narrow this list down further?

Selecting the second option in the popup list shows the following:

[image: Screenshot of CodeSense completion popup when second option selected]

To me this implies that if you type:

```
-tableView:n
```

you should get a completion list popup with only the methods that have that prefix. In fact all I get is 'No Completions'.

If instead I try to start typing the method signature verbatim:

```
-tableView:(
```

I then get an irrelevant completion list (it just lists types).

The above is just an example, I seem to come across this a lot when implementing interface methods.

I'm relatively new to Xcode (coming from a Visual Studio background), but I can't seem to find any information about this aspect of CodeSense.

Does Codesense support this sort of filtering, or am I just not using it correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I've never been particularly happy with code sense complete in this regard either. While Rudolf's answer does work, I find it more effort than just scrolling through the list.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that (at least for me) the best solution is to **type method's return type**. That filters out a lot of stuff. An example for `UITableView` would be:

```
- (NSInteger)t
- (BOOL)t
```

The first one gives me 3 and the other 6 suggestions, which is quite narrow.